Convert pandas merge code to pyspark join
I have small problem with pyspark. I try to rewrite code from pandas where I have:
df.merge(df2, how="outer", left_on=["b"], right_on=["b"])

And I have got columns b, a_x and a_y. But when I do it in pyspark like:
df.join(df2, how="outer", on=["b"])

I have got b, a and a. When I try to do df.select("a") I have got error: Reference "a" is ambiguous. What did I wrong?

I think you need to rename the a's, so they aren't the same.

Use this code to use different column names after using df.join, you can't have two columns with the same name.
result_df = joined_df.select(
    "b",
    F.col("a").alias("a_x"),
    F.col("a").alias("a_y")
)


The problem is that in real life I have no idea which column(s) will be doubled

@Nju check my answer for a more generic sol

If you have no idea about which columns can be doubled, you can alias your dataframes during the join
Example
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


# Generate dataset with more ambigous columns
data1 = [(1, "A", 100, "2024-10-01"), (2, "B", 200, "2024-10-02"), (3, "C", 300, "2024-10-03")]
data2 = [(1, "X", 110, "2024-11-01"), (2, "Y", 210, "2024-11-02"), (4, "Z", 310, "2024-11-03")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ["b", "a", "value", "date"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["b", "a", "value", "date"])

def get_suffixed_columns(df: DataFrame, df_alias: str):
    return [
       col(f"{df_alias}.{column_name}").alias(f"{column_name}_{df_alias}") for column_name in df.columns
    ]

# Join and select automatically the columns by suffixing with the df alias
df_merged = df.alias("x").join(df2.alias("y"), how="outer", on=["b"]).select(
    *get_suffixed_columns(df, "x"),
    *get_suffixed_columns(df2, "y")
)

Output
+----+----+-------+----------+----+----+-------+----------+
| b_x| a_x|value_x|    date_x| b_y| a_y|value_y|    date_y|
+----+----+-------+----------+----+----+-------+----------+
|   1|   A|    100|2024-10-01|   1|   X|    110|2024-11-01|
|   2|   B|    200|2024-10-02|   2|   Y|    210|2024-11-02|
|   3|   C|    300|2024-10-03|null|null|   null|      null|
|null|null|   null|      null|   4|   Z|    310|2024-11-03|
+----+----+-------+----------+----+----+-------+----------+


For
data1 = [(1, "A", 100, "2024-10-01"), (2, "B", 200, "2024-10-02"), (3, "C", 300, "2024-10-03")]
data2 = [(1, "X", 110, "2024-11-01"), (2, "Y", 210, "2024-11-02"), 3, "Z", 310, "2024-11-03")]
Create redundant _x, _y columns. I want to it works like for merge from pandas

One liner to rename the cols of a spark df:
prefix=“df1”
df1 = df1.select(*[prefix+”_”+x for x in df1.schema.columns()])

You could turn it into a function and rename a dataframes cols before performing the join.
Note that after renaming the Col names, your join statement’s “on” argument changed a bit as:
df1.join(df2, on= F.expr(“df1.df1_a = df2.df2_a”))

